# How to store 1 output from one script to another?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have `script1.ps1` with the following code:

```
Function Renew_Token($token) {
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("X-Vault-Token", $token)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod  -method POST -uri "https://vault.com:8243/v1/auth/token/renew-self" -ContentType 'application/json' -headers $headers
    $response| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100
}
Function getValues($token) {
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("X-Vault-Token", $token)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod  -method GET -uri "https://vault.com:8243/v1/secret/vault/development" -ContentType 'application/json' -headers $headers
    $response.data| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100
}
Renew_Token $token
write-host "token renewed!"
write-host "Vault Values:"
getValues $token
```

This gives me back a response like this:

```
{
    "request_id":  "ghgdf5-yuhgt886-gfd76trfd",
    "lease_id":  "",
    "renewable":  false,
    "lease_duration":  0,
    "data":  null,
    "wrap_info":  null,
    "warnings":  null,
    "auth":  {
                 "client_token":  "i657ih4rbg68934576y",
                 "accessor":  "t543qyt54y64y654y",
                 "policies":  [
                                  "default",
                                  "vault"
                              ],
                 "token_policies":  [
                                        "default",
                                        "vault"
                                    ],
                 "metadata":  null,
                 "lease_duration":  2000,
                 "renewable":  true,
                 "entity_id":  ""
             }
}
token renewed!
Vault Values:
{
    "abc":  "1234",
    "def":  "897",
    "klm":  "something12"
}
```

Now consider in a `Script2.ps1`, I call script1

```
$second_response = & ".\Script1.ps1"
```

of course, `$second_response` will store the 2 responses above as output.

How can i store JUST the second response as keys/values say in a table in Script2? i.e. this part:

```
{
    "abc":  "1234",
    "def":  "897",
    "klm":  "something12"
}

$HashTable = @{ }
$HashTable.Add($second_response.key, $second_response.value)
```

in other words, somehow the `$second_response` variable should only store this output:

```
{
    "abc":  "1234",
    "def":  "897",
    "klm":  "something12"
}
```

Note: that second response is considerably dynamic. meaning there could be different values on different environments. therefore, i want to be able to DYNAMICALLY store whatever is in this response, not hardcode the values

Also, I need the 2 responses in script 1 because i use script1 for other purposes, such as say i want to only view the vault content. script2 will have operations on the response from script1, so i have them separated for this convenience and flexibility

UPDATE: Following @kuzimoto suggestion, i removed the output and converting the response back from JSON, i get this output from Script2:

```
abc:  1234
def:  897
klm:  something12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet, but here's a couple possibilities:

1. Edit script1.ps1

You don't mention if you need the first set of results. If you don't, just simply delete or comment out this line `$response| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100` from the Renew_Token function.

2. Parse the output of script1.ps1 as json

You're passing the output of script1 to script2 as plain text. Simply change `$second_response = & ".\Script1.ps1"` to `$second_response = & ".\Script1.ps1" | ConvertFrom-Json`. Then when you want to access the second response, use `$second_response[1]` as both sets of JSON get added to a custom PS Object and can be accessed individually like you would an array.

Comment: what if i have in script1 some writehosts, for example: token renewed! would the JSON be recognized separately?  if i use this way: $second_response = & ".\Script1.ps1" | ConvertFrom-Json ? in other words, would only the JSON fragments be stored?

Comment: also, the reason i have them as two separate scripts is because lets say i wanna run script1 just for viewing purposes. script2 will have some operations i will apply on the response of script1, so thats why i have them separated, which is why i didnt comment out the output from response 1, so that the script is used conveniently for other things besides script2

Comment: Unfortunately it would try to convert all output from Script1 as JSON, so it would probably just error out.

Comment: yep :/ just tried it and it errored this: ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: Renewing. is there no way around this besides commenting out all other outputs i have? i really worked hard on some output explanations lol, it'd be a shame if i have to comment them out :(

Comment: At this point, you could try to separate out your functions in to a file by themselves, then import them into both Script1 and Script2, so that you can call the functions that you need without all the extra stuff.

Comment: If you're removing all output except the one you need, then you would access it with [0] instead of [1]. I didn't know you had other outputs, so I was assuming you would need to get the second JSON object in your original post.

Comment: yep i figured it out :) i didnt realize for a moment the index started from 0 haha.

Comment: ok so now that i have the $second_response[1], how do i put the values as key/value pair dynamically (as in no hardcoding) say in a hashtable or pscustomobject? convertfrom-json threw me back a nice list of the keys/values.

Comment: Convertfrom-json automatically creates a pscustomobject. There is no "JSON" object in PowerShell. You should be able to edit all the keys and their values with no problems, add new key/values, etc.

Comment: oh so thats why its outputting as a list (check the UPDATE section in my post)

Comment: so if its a pscutomobject its outputting, can i store them as keys/values like this: $HashTable = @{}

foreach($key in $second_response[1])
{
    $HashTable.Add($key.Name, $key.Value)
}

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right syntax. This should do it though: `$second_response[1].psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object { $HashTable.Add($_.Name, $_.Value)}`