# why is this command not executing with a TFS build?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have 2 powershell scripts

`script1.ps1` contains REST calls to Vault, which returns a json response containing some keys/values.

```
Function getValues($token) {
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("X-Vault-Token", $token)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod  -method GET -uri "https://vault.com:8243/v1/secret/vault/development" -ContentType 'application/json' -headers $headers
    $response.data| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100
}
getValues $token
```

suppose one of those keys in the response is as follows:

```
key1:value123
```

`script2.ps1` calls `scrip1.ps1` like this

```
$currentDirectory = "D:\\Scripts"
$response = & "$currentDirectory\script1.ps1" | ConvertFrom-Json
$pass = $response[1]."key1"
$pass
```

that block executes just fine if i am testing locally and i get `value123` as output as expected

now i set up a WinRM remote powershell task on TFS as part of the build which is calling `script2.ps1`.

of course i am logging pretty much everything to a log file in my `script2` so i can see all the output happpening, except the response. the response is not being returned whatsoever!

$pass is not printing anything back when i run the TFS build, but locally it prints just fine

is there something special i have to wrap this command with for TFS specifically? am i missing something here??

Comment: write-output maybe?

Comment: @lloyd nope, doesnt work. what i dont understand is i am not even trying to print this to TFS console but rather just get the value stored in the variable and use it somewhere else. its not storing anything

Comment: what does the response contain?

Comment: @lloyd key1:value123 . $pass then should contain value123. it works great locally, but building from TFS, nope

Comment: are you returning it as an array ```,$stuff``` in script 1? how are you stopping ps from returning logs in script 1?

Comment: @lloyd nope. check my post, i updated what i have in script1

Comment: ```Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/``` returns an array, so I shouldn't need to convert it back and forth from that point unless you want to pass it as a string. ```return ,$response``` should not require convertto-json and convertfrom-json?

Comment: @lloyd I followed the answer here, which has been working locally just fine ever since: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119686/8397835?

Comment: @Cataster where the both scripts exist? in the target machine or in the agent machine?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk the scripts are on target machine, which is why I chose powershell remote management (WinRM)

Comment: @Cataster Ok, did you try run the scripts in the agent machine (with the regular powershell tasl) just to check if it's works?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk i figured it out! so i was using an environment variable for the token set in USER env variables. Apparently it has to be saved in SYSTEM env variables

Comment: @lloyd figured it out finally!! see answer

Comment: Great! Nice catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue finally

We had the token saved in USER environment variables that the script was not able to call from. I think when I was testing because I was logged on on the server as said user, the script worked because it recognized the user and was able to fetch the environment variable.

However, when I am running from TFS using remote Powershell, its not recognizing the user env variable.

Setting the env variable token in SYSTEM env variables worked!